# A design pattern for async requests to handle success, failure, retry ? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, titanium-mobile

I'm writing a mobile app with Appcelerator Titanium that makes a lot of different xhr requests. This is not really an Appcelerator Titanium specific question. But if you do write some code, I hope it's javascript.

The app needs to authenticate itself, the user must be logged for some interactions, etc.

I've come to a point where any request might get any kind of response such as:

- not authenticated
- not logged
- bad params
- successful
- ...

The requests are wrapped in different model methods or helpers.

The thing is, I'm not familiar with this kind of app. I was wondering what are the best practices.

**Some real questions for example would be:**

- If the app is not authenticated (token expired, first launch), should the app try to authenticate itself and then send again the request that was denied ? (transparent to user)
- Should I send an authentication request each time the app launches and then "forget" about it?

The problem I'm facing is that the code becomes quickly big if I try to handle this for each request. Full of nested callbacks, retry conditions, various events listeners to manage, etc. It just does not feel very "nice". And it's not DRY at all, when what I really need is for any request, check what was wrong, try to fix it (authenticate if not, automatic login if possible or show the login UI, etc..) then if that works retry the original request a couple of times, abort if needed.

I've been looking at the promise pattern but only know theory and don't know if it could be what I need.

So I welcome any advice regarding this particular problem. I wonder how apps like "Facebook" handle this.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is not easily answered, but let me try to give you some Ideas:

The most important thing, before coding anything in your app, is the API itself. It has to be reliable and adhere to standards. I will not go into too much detail here, but a well written RESTful API can reduce the complexity of your httpClient significantly. It has to respond with standard http status codes and to methods like POST, GET, PUT, DELETE...

A pretty good read is [The REST API Design Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00890OBFI) by George Reese.

My approach to httpClients with Titanium is a single module, which is loaded via require() wherever needed. I stick to one single client at a time, as I had massive problems with multiple parallel calls. Whenever a call is made, the client checks if there is already a call in progress and sends it to a queue if necessary.

Let me show you an example. I have left out lots of stuff for sake of brevity:

```
// lib/customClient.js
var xhrRequest;     // This will be our HTTPClient
var callQueue = []; // This will be our queue

// Register the request
// params are:
// method (e.g. 'GET')
// url (e.g. 'http://test.com/api/v1/user/1')
// done (callback function)
function registerRequest(params) {
    if(!xhrRequest) {
        sendRequest(params);
    } else {
        queueRequest(params);
    }
}

// This simply sends the request
// to the callQueue
function queueRequest(params) {
    callQueue.push(params);
}

// Send the request with the params from register
// Please note that I do not hardcode error messages,
// I just do it here so it is easier to read
function sendRequest(params) {

    // Set callback if available and valid
    var callback = params.done && typeof(params.done) === "function" ? params.callback : null;

    // Set method
    var method = params.method || 'GET';

    // Create the HTTP Client
    xhrRequest = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        // Success
        onload: function() {
            // You can check for status codes in detail here
            // For brevity, I will just check if it is valid
            if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
                if(this.responseText) {
                    // You might want to check if it can be parsed as JSON here
                    try {
                        var jsonData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        if(callback) callback({ success: true, response: jsonData });
                    } catch(e) {
                        if(callback) callback({ success: false, errormessage: 'Could not parse JSON data' });
                    }
                    processQueue();
                } else {
                    if(callback) callback({ success: false, errormessage: 'No valid response received' });
                    processQueue();
                }
            } else {
                if(callback) callback({ success: false, errormessage: 'Call response is success but status is ' + this.status });
                processQueue();
            }
        },
        // Error
        onerror: function(e) {
            if(this.responseText) {
                try {
                    var jsonData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    if(callback) callback({ success: false, reponse: jsonData });
                } catch(e) {};
            }
            processQueue();
        },
    });

    // Prepare and send request
    // A lot more can (and should) be configured here, check documentation!
    xhrRequest.setTimeout(10000);
    xhrRequest.open(method, params.url);
    xhrRequest.send();
}

// Checks if there is anything else in the queue
// and sends it
function processQueue() {
    xhrRequest = null;
    var nextInQueue = callQueue.shift();
    if(nextInQueue) sendRequest(nextInQueue);
}

// Our public API
var publicAPI = {
    sendRequest: function(params) {
        registerRequest(params);
    }
};

module.exports = publicAPI;
```

I can then send a call from any other controller/view

```
var customClient = require('lib/customClient'); // omit 'lib' if you use alloy

// Send the request
customClient.sendRequest({
        method        : 'GET',
        url           : 'http://test.com/api/v1/user/1',
        done          : function(response) {
                           Ti.API.debug(JSON.stringify(response));
                        }
});
```

Note that this is not complete and does not check for connectivity, has no real error handling etc., but it might help you to get an idea.

I think there is loads of stuff to talk about here, but I will stop here for now...

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I think it's something "big" to answer. I believe the main idea in your case is to have a centralized XHR manager. It's also a good way to be able to cancel pending requests when needed. I'll investigate more.